# Executing Main class in Jar using batch file

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a runnable jar with main class located at /DataValidation/src/package/class 
i am using the following commands in batch file to run the main class but i am getting the error as could not find or load main class.

```
 @echo off
    javac -cp C:\Users\500603\Desktop\Excel_files\ivg\sample.jar; package.class.java
    java -cp C:\Users\500603\Desktop\Excel_files\ivg\sample.jar; .package.class
    pause
```

Please help me how can i execute the main class present in jar file

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Do you seriously have a file named package.class.java? Or package/class.java? If so, how would one ever manage to put anything remotely compilable into it? "package" and "class" are keywords. Also, if you have a runnable jar, you want -jar, not -cp. And what is the leading dot before "package" in line 3? What exactly is your error message?

Answer (score 1):

Create MANIFEST.MF file. Add line:

```
Main-Class: package.class
```

in jar, create META-INF folder and put manifest file into it.

`java -jar C:\Users\500603\Desktop\Excel_files\ivg\sample.jar` should work now.

P.S. package and class are very confusing names. Use something different.